# Each item height sometimes not being calculated

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if($('body').hasClass('single') && ($overlayPanel) ) {
    $overlayPanel.each(function(){
        $(this).height($(this).prev().height());
    })
}
```

It seems like 50% of the time the image's height isn't calculated in time before its asigned to create the overlayPanel's height (just results in height 0px). Is there a more robust way to write this so the overlayPanel will always have the prev()'s height?

Comment: Have you tried this code in window load instead of doc ready?

Answer (score 0):

You should prove that

- all images are loaded when this function is called (`$(document).ready()`)
- (or the images have a size set by css)
- the previous tag to each $overlayPanel in the dom is always the img tag

Answer (score 0):

If every element has the same height as the previous element, they all have the same height as the first one, so there surely are easier ways to write that at least.

For images you'll have to wait for the images to load before you can get the height, you can either use window.onload, or listen for the onload event for the first image and then set the height of the other images to the same height

```
if( $('body').hasClass('single') && $overlayPanel.length ) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        $overlayPanel.css('height', $(this).height())
    }
    img.src = $overlayPanel.first().prop('src');
    if (img.complete) img.onload();
}
```